# Using an Angular wrapped Jquery library

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular

I am currently trying to integrate a Jquery component with my Angular application.
The component is a homepage component that organizes widgets. My ultimate goal is to use this and handle the events (resize widget, remove widget) in the Angular code but I do not know how to identify which card the event happened on in the Angular context.

The Jquery portion just uses a class selector

```
const cards = homepage.element.find('.card, .widget');
```

and then triggers event handlers:

```
homepage.element.triggerHandler('resizecard', [card, homepage.state]);
```

Notice two things:

1. the event is triggered on the homepage component, not individual widgets and
2. the Jquery element for the target card is passed with the event.

The angular wrapper for a widget is like below.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'div[soho-widget]', // tslint:disable-line
  template: `<ng-content></ng-content>`,
})
export class SohoWidgetComponent {
  @HostBinding('class') get classList(): string {
```

and there are event emitters on the homepage component wrapping the events like:

```
.on('resizecard', (e: JQuery.TriggeredEvent, card: JQuery, metadata: object) => this.onResizeCard(card, metadata))
```

In my Angular application, each widget is it's own component that extends an abstract component class
**but** I cannot for the life of me figure out how to identify which widget the event is happening on in the Angular context.

Comment: whats the name of library you are using?

Comment: @Supercool I actually added this functionality to the jquery library. So I do have the ability to make changes at that level.

Comment: So did you check if you are able to catch event in widgets?

Comment: Not at the moment. I was hoping not to have to change the jquery code but I think that might be the only way.